# проверить реальный memory_limit

Tags: php

В phpinfo стоит 1024М. При запуске скрипта получаю Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes). В пересчёте на русский 128Мб использовано и 20Мб не хватило.

Как такое может быть? Что делать? В пхпинфо указывается реальный лимит или номинальный, который должен быть? Может ли хостер намахивать, рубая лимиты?

Comment: прочитайте детали тарифа у хостера.

Comment: чтобы кстати лимит поменялся, надо апач перезапустить.а фактически проверять ничего не надо, вам черным по белому написано, доступный лимит 128Мбайт исчерпан. В любом случая для типичной работы пхп 128мбайт это очень много. Если вы не открываете какие-нибудь  большие XML и т.п. подобные файлы, то ищите проблему в коде, возможно какая-то рекурсия у вас из под контроля выходит.

Comment: Это как раз тот случай. Я парсю прайс xml в 20+ Мб. Но суть даже не в этом. Лимит стоит в 1024мб, а фактически сброс скрипта выполняется при 128Мб. Почему оставшаяся память не используется ?

Comment: первый коммент еще раз прочитайте

Comment: По сути вы пересказываете суть вопроса другими словами и не даёте ответ на вопрос ни в первом, ни во втором комменте. Вопрос заключается в том, что лимит в 1024мб, а сброс происходит уже при 128мб

Comment: если у виртуальной машины лимит 128мбайт хоть что вы пишите в конфиге пхп, больше памяти вы не получите. это более понятно или еще что-то надо?

Comment: У тарифного плана лимит в 1024 мб и это же отражено в пхпинфо, на это и ссылается хостер. Но сброс скрипта происходит при гораздо меньшей нагрузке - 128 мб.

Comment: Унылый хостинг значит! Подменили ``phpinfo`, чтобы рубить денежку на низших тарифах, встречал уже таких мудил. Самое правильно решение, просто поменять хостинг и не мучиться. Кстати, что за хост?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вопрос решается строкой

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
```

прописанной в начале скрипта.
Как ни странно, несмотря на то, что хостер заявляет о `memory_limit = 1024Мб` для моего тарифа, в `phpinfo` также отображается 1024Мб, по факту реально лимит стоял на 128Мб. Установка настройки конфигурации с помощью [ini_set](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.ini-set.php) в начале скрипта указанным способом решает вопрос.