# Разбиение скрипта на части

Tags: php, парсер

Есть скрипт, который парсит прайс в формате `XML`. Он написан так, что берёт в память объект `XML` и преобразует его в нужный вид, передавая данные из метода в метод. Поэтапного выполнения, насколько я понимаю это понятие, - нет. Возникла проблема с большим `XML`.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что если я в некоторых участках кода буду записывать данные во временные файлы и очищать память, а потом для работы с этими данными доставать данные из файла, то я смогу добиться некоего подобия поэтапности: выполнил часть - записал, очистил память... вычисляю следующий фрагмент... опять записываю в другой файл и очистка памяти.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что:

1. Промежуточными точками, которые будут формировать этапы и будет в данном случае запись данных в файл и очистка памяти?
2. Лучше всего очистить память - это `unset($a)`?

Скорость работы для меня не сильно критична, т.к. запускается дело кроном, а не юзером, для меня важно побороть `memory_limit` при большом файле `XML`.

Comment: Если у вас не потоковое чтение xml файла, то вам не поможет никакая очистка.

Comment: Хотелось бы получить аргументированный ответ. В некоторых участках я планирую освобождать оперативу, чтоб хранящиеся в памяти переменные её не забивали и она использовалась для вычислений. Что не так в задуманном?

Comment: Всё это не имеет смысла, если у вас php загрузит целиком и сразу весь xml файл. Высвобождать память из своих переменных становится как-то глупо, если вы не превзойдёте по объёму сам xml файл.

Comment: С помощью get_memory_usage() я замерил объем выделяемой памяти на первом этапе - когда получался первый объект  из xml. Она составила 46мб из 128 имеющихся. Далее этот объект мнётся и преобразовуется в нужный вид. И походу это преобразование и не вмещается в лимит. Не совсем понял, что вы имеете ввиду под «превзойти по обьёму сам xml”

Comment: 46 мегабайт?! Серьёзно? Большой - это 1 - 10 ГБ (правильно говорить "соизмеримый с объёмом оперативной памяти). А у вас проще вместо 128 поставить 256 - 512 мб в настройках пхп

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1074194/311431 не хотел бы мешать эти вопросы, но они из одной оперы. У меня в настройках и в условиях тарифа стоит memory_limit 1024мб, но обрывается скрипт при нагрузке в 128мб. Т.к. первый вопрос с лимитом ( о чем вы и говорите выше) я не решил, пытаюсь решить его другим методом, задав текущий вопрос. Возможно да, надо как-то увеличить до заявленных 1024мб, но это пока не получается, поэтому прошу помощи в оптимизации.

Comment: Может все таки еще раз попробовать увеличить мемори лимит? Например `ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
`

Comment: Ну или https://habr.com/ru/post/330240/

Comment: Можно разбить на 2ва скрипта, первый достанет всё из xml запишет в БД элементы, второй будет брать из БД и делать все манипуляции (брать можно не все имеющиеся а ограниченное число), хотя если это сделать в виде одного скрипта то и получится скрипт по шагам, например в базу пишите сейчас 1 шаг, парсите xml записываете в БД данные +записываете что шаг теперь 2, при следующем запуске скрипта если в БД 2рой шаг считываете обрабатываете данные (2рой шаг может быть большим например если брать из БД 100 записей после обработки удалять, потом ещё 100 и так пока не закончатся, потом записать шаг 3 ).

Comment: Вам нужно смотреть в сторону потокового процессинга вашего XML, примеры есть на англоязычном SO (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911663/parsing-huge-xml-files-in-php)